# PHP code Ancient Egyptian Multiplication javascript

Tags: javascript, php

The algorithm is as follows. If A and B are the 2 integers (only integers) to
be multiplied, we repeatedly multiply A by 2 and divide B by 2, until B
can’t be divided any further, that is until its value becomes 0 (remember,
this is integer division). During each step, whenever B is an odd number,
we add the corresponding A value to the product we are generating. In the
end, the sum of the A values that had corresponding odd B values is the
product. Get it?

Here’s an example:

If the two integers to be multiplied are 34 and 19, the operations would be:

```
A       B       Comment

34     19       add A to the product, B is odd
68      9        add A to the product, B is odd
136    4        ignore this A value, B is even
272    2        ignore this A value, B is even
544    1        add A to the product, B is odd
```

Sum up all the A values that had odd B values and you get:

34 + 68 + 544 = 646   => Final Product

Comment: search in google by "If A and B are the 2 integers (only integers) to be multiplied, we repeatedly multiply A by 2 and divide B by 2," AND You will get a link as [doc]. download and read.

Comment: show us what 've you tried

Comment: Please do not ask us for a full solution for your exercise. Show what you've done already and where you have a problem.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As your algorithm says.

```
$a = 34; 
$b = 19;

$total = 0;
do{
    $mod = $b % 2;
    if($mod){
        $total = $total + $a;
    }
    echo $mod." - ".$a." - ".$total . "<br/>"; //Steps
    $a = $a * 2;
    $b = floor($b/2);
}while($b > 0);
echo $total; // 646
```

**Steps:**

```
Mod       $a         $total
---------------------------
1     -   34     -   34
1     -   68     -   102
0     -   136    -   102
0     -   272    -   102
1     -   544    -   646
```